# Expressing do block using only monadic bind syntax

Tags: haskell, scope, monads, code-translation, do-notation

As far as I know, `do` blocks in Haskell are just some kind of syntactic sugar for monadic bind operators. For example, one could convert

```haskell
main = do f <- readFile "foo.txt"
          print f
          print "Finished"
```

to

```haskell
main = readFile "foo.txt" >>= print >> print "Finished"
```

Can all `do` blocks be converted to bind syntax? What about, for example, this block where `f` is used multiple times:

```haskell
main = do f <- readFile "foo.txt"
          print $ "prefix " ++ f
          print $ f ++ " postfix"
```

Assuming we are in the IO monad, it is not possible to simply execute the `readFile` computation twice. How can this example (if possible at all) expressed using only bind syntax?

I think using `Control.Monad` is no solution, because it internally uses `do` blocks.

I think it it's possible to express this using arrows (using `&&&`) -- maybe this is a case where only arrows can be used as *a generalization of monads*?

Note that this question is not about the special examples above but about the general case of the result of a computation being used multiple times in monadic expressions like `print`.

Comment: Often this makes your code prettier. `Control.Applicative` has a bunch of operators you can use to mess with stuff of type `m a`, then you can `>>=` to the output. Usually that's much prettier. Sometimes point free isn't prettier at all; we could write `main = readFile "foo.txt" >>= flip mapM_ [("prefix" ++), (++ "postfix")] . (print .) . flip id` but that wouldn't be very clear.

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks for your suggestion! In this particular case I was only interested in how to convert the do syntax and I intended to keep it simple. Generally, I fully agree to you that applicative is the correct tool here. Besides, is there any specific reason why you don't use `forM_` instead of `flip mapM_`?

Comment: Because I forgot it! :) Let's pretend it was for another reason like avoiding importing `Control.Monad`. Trouble with that is that if you don't import `Control.Monad`, you miss the lovely `(>=>) :: Monad m => (a->m b) -> (b->m c) -> (a -> m c)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, all of them can be converted to bind syntax; in fact, they are converted internally by the compiler.

I hope this translation of your example gives you the hint:

```
main = readFile "foo.txt" >>= \f ->
       (print $ "prefix " ++ f) >>
       (print $ f ++ " postfix")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Lambda expressions were the key part I was missing!

Answer (score 8):

The [Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) gives a full translation from do syntax into kernel Haskell:

> Do expressions satisfy these identities, which may be used as a translation into the kernel, after eliminating empty stmts:
>
> ```
> do {e}                = e
> do {e;stmts}          = e >> do {stmts}
> do {p <- e; stmts}    = let ok p = do {stmts}
>                             ok _ = fail "..."
>                         in e >>= ok
> do {let decls; stmts} = let decls in do {stmts}
> ```
>
> The ellipsis "..." stands for a compiler-generated error message, passed to fail, preferably giving some indication of the location of the pattern-match failure; the functions >>, >>=, and fail are operations in the class Monad, as defined in the Prelude; and ok is a fresh identifier.

So your example translates this way:

```
do f <- readFile "foo.txt"
   print $ "prefix " ++ f
   print $ f ++ " postfix"
=
let ok f = do print $ "prefix " ++ f
              print $ f ++ " postfix"
    ok _ = fail "..."
in readFile "foo.txt" >>= ok
=
let ok f = (print $ "prefix " ++ f) >> do print $ f ++ " postfix"
    ok _ = fail "..."
in readFile "foo.txt" >>= ok
=
let ok f = (print $ "prefix " ++ f) >> (print $ f ++ " postfix")
    ok _ = fail "..."
in readFile "foo.txt" >>= ok
```

This version has no `do` blocks, but doesn't look very natural. But we can apply equational reasoning and whatever optimizations we know. So, for example, observing that the `ok _ = fail "..."` clause is dead code, we could inlike `ok` like so:

```
 =
 readFile "foo.txt" >>= \f ->
 (print $ "prefix " ++ f) >>
 (print $ f ++ " postfix")
```

All `do` blocks can be mechanically translated into code without `do` in this way.