# How are expressions allowed inside Haskell do blocks

Tags: haskell, code-translation, do-notation, code-transformation

In the following code, line 4, I have an expression sandwiched between two IO actions in a do block:

```
  1 doubleX :: (Show x, Num x) => x -> IO ()                                                                                                                                                                                          
  2 doubleX x = do                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  3   putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x))                                                                                                                                                                                     
  4   let double = x * 2                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  5   putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))
```

I understand do notation as chaining monadic operations together using >>= or >>. But how does that work when you have an expression in between? You couldn't just glue lines 3-5 together using >>.

Comment: It is glued as a `let .. in ` statement

Comment: But what would that look like if it were "desugared".

Comment: `putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x)) >> let double = x*2 in putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))`

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. I was thinking the let was a standalone expression that could be replaced with something like 1 + 2. This makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to crib from my very similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959366/791604) (though probably not a duplicate since that question doesn't explicitly deal with `let`).

The [Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) gives a full translation from do syntax into kernel Haskell; the parts relevant to your question are:

> ```
> do {e}                = e
> do {e;stmts}          = e >> do {stmts}
> do {let decls; stmts} = let decls in do {stmts}
> ```

So your code desugars like this:

```
doubleX x = do                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x))                                                                                                                                                                                     
  let double = x * 2                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))

==> do {e;stmts} rule

doubleX x =
  putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x)) >> do
  let double = x * 2                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))

==> do {let decls; stmts} rule

doubleX x =
  putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x)) >>
  let double = x * 2 in do
  putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))

==> do {e} rule

doubleX x =
  putStrLn ("I will now double " ++ (show x)) >>
  let double = x * 2 in
  putStrLn ("The result is " ++ (show double))
```