# Using Haskell to put timestamp in filenames

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Long story short: I am using XMonad and trying to put dynamic timestamps on screen-recordings.

I could have cheated and solved this by making it a bash script that easily lets you use changing timestamps, but I figured it was a good opportunity to dig into meat of Haskell.

The code I have tried to use:

```hs
import Data.Time
timeStamp = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d—%H:%M:%S" <$> getCurrentTime
```

then in keybindings I have put

```hs
        , ("M-<Print>", spawn $ "giph -f 60 -y -s  ~/recordings/" ++ timeStamp ++ ".mp4")
```

which give me the error of

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO String’
```

I figured this is related to Haskell not letting its variables change value, but I have no idea how to work around this or how to rewrite it so that I wouldn't need to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `=` you have just defined another function. Use `<-` to bind the result of a monadic action to a variable:

```hs
timeStamp <- formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d—%H:%M:%S" <$> getCurrentTime

-- ...

"~/recordings/" ++ timeStamp ++ ".mp4"
```

Comment: Is there any other way to bind the action's result to a variable? I don't want to make a function with "do"—which using <- requires—if I can avoid it.

Comment: @CrimsonCrusader Can you say a bit about why you want to avoid `do`? Certainly [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959366/791604), but `do` syntax is quite idiomatic.

Comment: @CrimsonCrusader Then try `timeStamp >>= \t -> return $ "~/recordings/" ++ t ++ ".mp4"`

Comment: @DanielWagner I reflected upon your query and figured I was being unreasonable. The final solution was to use a do block and combine it with `liftIO`+spawn from xmonad core package. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, you cannot "mix" IO with generic types. There are ways to get around this, though. For example, you could use the following to utilize an `IO String` as a generic `String`

```hs
myIOThing >>= \regular -> <do_something>
```

You can find more about it here
https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_get_rid_of_IO#Using_I.2FO_actions_more_directly